# Where has Meta of GIS Stack Exchange gone?

Tags: discussion, meta

The format of the pages for GIS Stack Exchange has changed, and the link to Meta is no longer where it was on the top bar.

Did I miss an announcement?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Still here just now in the top bar.

[image]

and if it ever disappears from there a fallback is to look for it at http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com

The only announcement of this change seems to have been made on **[Meta of StackOverflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/207420/the-new-top-bar-is-out-on-meta-consider-it-a-beta)**.

Comment: Grief!!!! totally didn't see that...initially it listed all of the StackExchange sites.  Only upon refreshing did it allow the option

Answer (score 9):

**It's also at the bottom of the help menu.**

[image]

Answer (score 9):

The [announcement](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2013/12/a-new-top-bar-for-stack-exchange/) was made on the Stack Exchange blog: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/

> ## A New Top Bar for Stack Exchange
>
> The top bar of a Stack Exchange site has always been a bit of an odd place. It somehow combines user info, navigation, search, and a one-size-fits-all popup that includes hot network questions, a list of 100+ Stack Exchange sites, personal inbox messages, and other system notifications (lovingly referred to as [The StackExchange™ MultiCollider SuperDropdown™](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=StackExchange%E2%84%A2%20MultiCollider%20SuperDropdown%E2%84%A2)).
>
> It was, in retrospect, overdue for a face-lift which is why we’re excited to roll out a new top bar this week.
>
> [image]

It would be nice if these kinds of changes showed up as a notification on the child sites though.