# Meta GIS URLs being switched around

Tags: discussion, bug, status-bydesign

I have noticed today several Q&As on GIS Meta have been modified by user *Community*.  When looking at what had changed, the edit was an update of Meta URLs from HTTP to HTTPS (as announced was happening in a featured [Meta SE Q&A](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/292058/network-wide-https-its-time) recently).

But looking closer at the edits I noticed that the actual URL subdomain order had been changed.  Where the link previously may have been 
***meta***.**gis**.stackexchange.com  where the `gis` comes after the `meta`, it has now changed to ***gis***.**meta**.stackexchange.com where the `gis` now comes before the `meta`.

[image]

Is this change correct or has the *Community* user broken how links work in Meta?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This change to URL structure is correct.  If you look at the URL in your browser now you will see the updated structure with the expected `https` as well as `gis.meta`.

[image]

And if you type into your address bar `meta.gis.stackexchange.com` it will automatically update to `https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com`.

This is correct, was planned, and was listed as a change in the same Meta SE Q&A that announced the change to HTTPS.

> 9. **(Child metas)** Move from meta.*.stackexchange.com to *.meta.stackexchange.com.

<s>As yet I am unsure the reason for this change, and have added a comment on the Meta SE Q&A asking about the purpose.</s>

The reason for this change is because you can have wildcards to the left of an address for a site certificate e.g. `*.meta.stackexchange.com` but not a wildcard in the middle of an address like `meta.*.stackexchange.com`, so it makes it easier to apply certificates to meta sites if they are all a subdomain of Meta.

> Ok so the top level domains are easy, a SAN cert which allows many
>   domains on a single cert – we can sanely combine up to 100 here. So
>   what about all of our `*.stackexchange.com` domains? A wildcart cert,
>   excellent we’re knocking these out like crazy. What about
>   `meta.*.stackexchange.com`? Damn. Can’t do that. You can’t have a
>   wildcard of that form - at least not one supported by most major
>   browsers, which means effectively it’s not an option. Let’s see where
>   these restrictions originate.
>   Section 3.1 of RFC 2818 is very open/ambiguous on wildcard usage, it
>   states:
>
> > Names may contain the wildcard character `*` which is considered to match any single domain name component or component fragment. E.g.,
> >     `*.a.com` matches `foo.a.com` but not `bar.foo.a.com`. `f*.com` matches `foo.com` but not `bar.com`.

From [Stackoverflow.com: the road to SSL](https://nickcraver.com/blog/2013/04/23/stackoverflow-com-the-road-to-ssl/)

This may mean that some Q&As that link to the old GIS Meta site directly, such as [this answer](https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3457/64785) to [Where has Meta of GIS Stack Exchange gone?](https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3456/where-has-meta-of-gis-stack-exchange-gone) may still refer to the old site, however an auto-direct is currently in place to send you to the correct site anyway.